# Writing group ranking without for-loops in Python + NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, performance, for-loop, rank

My goal is two create a function that takes in two input arrays and outputs ranks withing groups. More specifically, the first input to the function is an array of scores (`scores`, and the second input array is an array of group sizes (`groups`, in such a way that the sum of the group sizes equals the total amount of scores, and the scores array can be partitioned into groups doing something like `np.split(scores, np.cumsum(groups))`. The output ranking should be 1 for the point with the highest score within its group, two for the second highest, and so on. I have implemented this as follows (including two test cases):

```
import numpy as np


def assign_ranks(scores, groups):
    # Create an array to store the ranks
    ranks = np.zeros(len(scores), dtype=int)

    # Iterate through groups
    start = 0
    for group_size in groups:
        end = start + group_size
        ranks[start:end] = (-scores[start:end]).argsort().argsort() + 1
        start = end

    return ranks


def test():
    # Test case 1
    scores1 = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
    groups1 = np.array([3, 2])
    result1 = assign_ranks(scores1, groups1)
    print("Test case 1 result:", result1)  # Expected: [3 1 2 2 1]
    assert np.all(result1 == np.array([3, 1, 2, 2, 1]))

    # Test case 2
    scores2 = np.array([0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.4])
    groups2 = np.array([4, 3, 2])
    result2 = assign_ranks(scores2, groups2)
    print("Test case 2 result:", result2)  # Expected: [1 3 2 4 3 2 1 1 2]
    assert np.all(result2 == np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

While this works correctly, I was wondering if it would be possible to implement this without using for-loops, potentially improving performance. I have made several attemps with no success. Any suggestions?

I have tried other approaches, leveraging `np.lexsort` and `np.split`, for example. Nothing worked.

Comment: There is certainly a solution using twice more global sort but this would be inefficient. In fact, the current solution is not efficient because of the 2 `argsort` (and maybe the loop you want to remove too). I advise you to use Numba in this case (with plain loops to avoid creating many temporary arrays) and replace the second `argsort` with a source-destination inversion (running in `O(n)`). Sorting items is expensive.

Comment: I figured I can do something like `ranks[start:end][argsort] = np.arange(1, group_size + 1)` where `argsort = (-scores[start:end]).argsort()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your values are positive you can offset them by a base value corresponding to a multiple of the group index they are in.  Then use argsort to obtain the global positions of items with the offsets.  This will keep the members of a given group together relative to the group index.  Then convert the global indexes back into group relative positions and invert the  order to obtain ranks:

```
def assign_ranks(scores,groups):
    offsets   = np.repeat(np.arange(groups.size),groups) * np.max(scores)
    order     = np.argsort(scores + offsets)
    groupBase = np.repeat(np.cumsum(groups),groups)
    return groupBase - order
```

If you have negative values, you'll need to compute a larger offset (than `* np.max(scores)`) to ensure that there is no overlap across groups in the resulting values.

You could do this using `* 2 * np.max(np.abs(scores))`

or `* (np.max(scores) - np.min(scores))`

Comment: Very smart, thanks!